# Spring Batch base step with listeners

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to setup a base step has a logger listener attached for making sure that all the error logs end up in the correct file.

The setup below i simple enough and rather similar to the example presented on http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#mergingListsOnStep but according http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd, it seems that listeners don't belong under step but rather under tasklet.

```
<step id="baseLoggedStep">
    <listeners>
        <listener>
            <bean class="org.example...StepLogListener"/>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</step>

<step id="myJobStep" parent="baseLoggedStep">
... 
</step>
```

So, who is correct and how do I use the correct xsd to produce the desired result?

The following base step seems to do the trick, where StepLogListener listener implements StepExecutionListener.

```
<batch:step id="baseLoggedStep" abstract="true">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="stepLogListener">
                <bean class="com.bossmedia.gem.platform.batch.StepLogListener"/>
            </batch:listener>
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

However it doesn't seem optimal and frankly not entirely correct. This would mean that baseLoggedStep is an abstract instance of TaskletStep right?

Answer (score 1):

According to Spring Batch 2.1 XSD all you would need to do is make your first baseLoggedStep step example abstract (see [5.1.2.1. Abstract Step](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)).

Be aware of the fact that if your child jobs add their own listeners they will have to merge them (see [5.1.2.2. Merging Lists](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html)) or the listener(s) from your abstract parent step will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this example of a Spring Batch Step Execution Listener out there since I didn't see a good one online. Plus, the Spring reference example will not run as written.

```
<beans:bean id="customStepExecutionListener" class="com.foo.MyCustomStepExecutionListener" />
<beans:bean id="customJobExecutionListener" class="com.foo.MyCustomJobExecutionListener" />

<!-- Abstract step listener must be defined outside job -->     
<step id="abstractListeningStep" abstract="true">
    <!-- Must be inside tasklet, but tasklet does not affect firing order -->
    <tasklet>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="customStepExecutionListener" />
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>  
</step>

<!-- The job -->
<job id="myJob">
    <description>My Job</description>

    <listeners>
        <!-- Any job specific listeners here -->
        <listener ref="customJobExecutionListener" />
    </listeners>

    <!-- Start here -->
    <step id="myFirstStep" parent="abstractListeningStep">
        <!-- Your work/jobs/tasklets here -->
    </step>
</job>
```